# Sum the increment and return the next number

Tags: c#

Is there a way to calculate how many time increment of the value and return the next value.

> eg 0001 + 0002 + 0003

when it return the result is 0004

i did this

```
int num = 77;
int sum = 0;
for (int n = num; n > 0; sum += n % 10, n /= 10) ;
```

but this method sum up the int num to '14'

i want is int num '0001' than it continue to increase to '0002','0003'

Comment: Can you post some code for the issue you are having? A lot depends on that

Comment: your question is not clear, Add some code or proper example.

Comment: i already edit the question. it is ok

Comment: @David - If any of the answers solved your question please mark question as solved :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not directly but you can wrap with properties:

```
public int Counter { get; private set; } 

private int _number;
public int Number
{
    get { return _number; }
    set
    {
        _number = value;
        Counter++;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Let the method will give you the next result which is defined as like the following:

```
public static string GetTheNextResult(ref int number)
{
    return (++number).ToString("0000");
}
```

Let `numberInput`  be the number then you can use the following call to get next results:

```
int numberInput = 1;
var result1 = GetTheNextResult(ref numberInput); // Gives you 0002
var result2 = GetTheNextResult(ref numberInput); // Gives you 0003
var result3 = GetTheNextResult(ref numberInput); // Gives you 0004
```